# How do I correctly add the hr button to the Quill editor?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, quill

How do I correctly add the `hr` button to the `Quill editor`? I add this button to the `toolbar`, and then in the `@ready` event I execute the following code:

```
quill.getModule('toolbar').handlers['hr'] = () => {
    const cursorPosition = quill.getSelection().index;
    quill.insertText(cursorPosition, '\n\n<hr>\n\n', 'user');
    quill.setSelection(cursorPosition + 4);
}
```

This code doesn't work. When I try to output to the console this:

```
quill.getModule('toolbar').handlers['hr']
```

The browser gives me `undefined`. But when I output to the console this:

```
quill.getModule('toolbar').handlers
```

The browser shows that there is a nested `hr` field in the `handlers` field.

I'm using the `Quill` version for `Nuxt 3` and `Vue`.